# What happened to "Ignore keyboard volume buttons." preference in VLC?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, alsa, pulse-audio

On my Debian system, VLC 2.2.1 is responding to my laptop's volume keys, and *also* forwarding them to the system, so when VLC is open the keys adjust both volumes simultaneously. Basically, I'm seeing the same issue as described here: [How do I stop VLC from stealing my volume buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/197821/how-do-i-stop-vlc-from-stealing-my-volume-buttons) , except on Debian.

Frustratingly, an answer to that question states a preference was added to control this in 1.1.7. In 2.2.1, this preference "Ignore keyboard volume buttons" is nowhere to be found.

I discovered in the 'Hotkeys' section that volume up/volume down were both listing two hotkeys, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>=Volume Up is what was listed for volume up), but unsetting these and just setting to the Ctrl-arrow combos has no impact on the behavior.

Is this now located somewhere else, or is there another way to adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Ignore keyboard volume buttons" option was [introduced in 2010](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/commit/b4ca80b9b1dcd529be276d46961fd40749b3f5d8), but only for Windows. [It is still Windows-only in the latest version](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/664045fb5e547a88d04f381dce20bf8ef5af10d3/modules/gui/qt/qt.cpp#L331).

For other operating systems, I also cannot possibly find a way to disable this behavior. It should however be pretty straightforward to enable this also for Linux in a custom build, or better, submit a patch for it.