# How can I disable media keys processing in vlc media player?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, default-settings, media-keys, configure

The title is self explanatory. There is no such option in vlc settings though [this](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=80652#p288339) page says that the configuration option for this option was added to gui in vlc-1.1.7. The page is quite old though.

Comment: Have you looked into cvlc?

Comment: typing `help` on cvlc gives a list of commands which can be used to control the playback, nothing related to configuration. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1060895/379095, but it does not have an answer either

Comment: The linked post has since gotten answered by phil294. While it mentions how to ignore volume-related media buttons on Windows, it unfortunately does not cover play/pause and others.