# In kmplayer (or vlc or any player) how do you deactivate the bluetooth next/previous function when remapping keys?

Tags: vlc-media-player, kmplayer

I bought a bluetooth remote that I want to use to fastforward/rewind in KMPlayer using the next/previous or volume buttons. If I set the buttons in the preferences to fast forward/rewind five seconds when I press next/back the hotkey still activates the next/back track (or volume if I use volume keys). The forward and reverse hotkeys are not set in the preferences so there is no key to deactivate the native behavior. The same thing happens in VLC. How can I deactivate the native next/back function on the remote?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/197821/how-do-i-stop-vlc-from-stealing-my-volume-buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by using [media player classic-hc](https://mpc-hc.org/) which had the option to unset the medianext, mediaprevious native functionality hotkey and then set the medium back/forward distance (which is 5 secs) to the medianext/mediaprevious app function hotkey which is the only way I got this to work without the native next track/forward track firing at the same time as the jump forward/back.

---

I also could keep using the mouse wheel for ff/back but I wanted to watch videos using my bt remote since that's what I bought it for.