# How do I stop SMPlayer from using volume buttons?

Tags: audio, volume-mixer, mpv

My question is almost exactly the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/197821/how-do-i-stop-vlc-from-stealing-my-volume-buttons), except that I am asking in reference to using SMPlayer, not VLC.

When I press the volume buttons on my keyboard usually the system volume is changed, however when SMPlayer has focus the volume keypresses are sent to its own "volume" while the system volume is also being changed simultaneously.

There is a feature within the SMPlayer Audio settings to '*use software volume control*' which is supposed to disable this, however it seems that turning this on and off had no effect whatsoever.

[image]

The version I am using is **20.4.3 (revision 9306) (64 bit)** on Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block the volume keys from reaching SMPlayer and do the volume change
yourself. You may use for that the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will intercept the volume keys if the title of
the active window contains "SMPlayer" and will change the volume by
increments of `2`:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2      ; A window's title can contain string anywhere to be a match
#IfWinActive SMPlayer     ; Applies to windows whose title contains "SMPlayer"
Volume_Down::SoundSet, -2 ; Volume down key : Reduce sound volume by 2
Volume_Up::SoundSet, +2   ; Volume up key : Increase sound volume by 2
```

This will also disable the display of the Volume Pop-Up Display
for SMPlayer.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the
green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [SoundSet](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm)

Comment: this is very helpful! Thanks Harrymc ! I will award bounty when I am allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Those keys (among others) are configured as shortcuts by default.

To change that go to Preferences->Mouse and Keyboard->(Tab)Keyboard...
Order the table by Description to find the shortcuts Volume+- (Or something) quickly. There i trust you to know how to edit them.

Comment: This is the better answer